# How to modify all lines in a file following a regex-matched line

Tags: sed

For instance, the following text file:

```
original line 1
original line 2
original line 3
original pattern
original line 5
original line 6
original line 7
```

should be transformed into:

```
original line 1
original line 2
original line 3
original pattern
modified line 5
modified line 6
modified line 7
```

The number of lines to modify after the matched pattern is not fixed.

The following sed command can print all lines after the matched pattern:

```
$ sed -n '/^original pattern$/ { :a; n; p; ba; }' file.txt
original line 5
original line 6
original line 7
```

But how can we modify them in the file?

Comment: Maybe `sed '/^original pattern$/{:a;n;s/original/modified/g;ta}' file`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **GNU** sed:

```
sed '0,/original pattern/b; s/original/modified/' file
```

Output:

```
original line 1
original line 2
original line 3
original pattern
modified line 5
modified line 6
modified line 7
```

Comment: This can also be written as:  `sed '0,/^original pattern$/!s/original/modified/' file`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk`, with your shown samples, following may help you on same.

```
awk 'found{sub(/original line/,"modified line")} /original pattern/{found=1} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
found{                                   ##Checking condition if found is SET then do following.
  sub(/original line/,"modified line")   ##Substituting original line(as regexp) with modified line here.
}
/original pattern/{                      ##Checking if line has original pattern then do following.
  found=1                                ##Set found here.
}
1                                        ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a POSIX compliant sed command to do the same:

```sh
sed '/^original pattern$/,$ {/pattern$/!s/original/modified/;}' file

original line 1
original line 2
original line 3
original pattern
modified line 5
modified line 6
modified line 7
```

Comment: I wrote it this way too, but the problem is: what happens if the original pattern shows up more than once? Subsequent lines don't get modified.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. I guess I made an assumption that pattern will appear only once.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/{:a;n;s/original/modified/;ba}' file
```

Find the line with `pattern`.

Print the line, fetch the next, replace `original` by `modified` and repeat.

N.B. The `n` command will terminate the sed cycle if it tries to read beyond the end of the file.